# gameobjects installation for python

Tags: python

I have a programming book that i use to progress in python and it's really good. However, there is one module in the book that i can't install. I have tried everything. I tried pip install, i tried to contact the author of the book. I also tried to install it from PyPip, but notthing seem to work. I need to install the module to begin with 3d grapichs and start understanding how it works. I know i could use Numpy, but the book only shows this module and therfore i need to install it. Can someone help me install the GameObjects module?

Comment: Which module is it? Is is this one? https://pypi.org/project/gameobjects/ cause if so it was release in 2007 with python 2.7

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes Paul it was that one. Do i have to have python 2.7 for it or what?

Comment: I've converted it;  I'll post a link shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to clone a Python3 version from https://github.com/timrprobocom/gameobjects . At least, all the tests pass.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it doesn't work. It says "Installing gameobjects" in PyCharm, but then it says "failed to install gameobjects". Also, i have tried to install it on their website but it doesn't work. I tried to install it through GHub with your link, but i don't know how to use GHub. Can you explain to me or should i just give up?

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/timrprobocom/gameobjects.git` / `cd gameobjects` / `python3 setup.py install`.